# I2C driver not load (Failed to register i2c client -16)

Tags: linux-kernel, driver, i2c

I have some devices on i2c bus.
I use DTS for probe driver, but I cannot probe one of driver.
Device have address (0x20) kernel send me message:

`i2c i2c-0: Failed to register i2c client mcp23017 at 0x20 (-16)`

Device is mcp2301 and I can detect it

```
 i2cdetect -y 0
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
 00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
 10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- UU -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
 20: 20 UU -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
 30: -- -- -- -- UU -- -- -- -- -- UU -- -- -- -- -- 
 40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- UU 
 50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- UU -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
 60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
 70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

As you can see, same device (0x21 also mcp2301) is working fine.

When I use i2cget/i2cset I can properly control this device (0x20).
I also tried turn i2cdebug in kernel. But nothing interesting - because driver of 0x20 device not probe(not enter to probe function).

I tried mcp230xx driver and my own driver, both same behaviour.

Thanks

Update:

Complet dts is [here](http://pastebin.com/jif9TzX3).My dts overlay[here](http://pastebin.com/8Yt7Pz6a). And dmesg with initcall_debug [here](http://pastebin.com/nCzWLA1r). Finaly [here](http://pastebin.com/Nhpc9aWV) is my drive (but also I  try gpio-mcp23s08.c driver with same error).

Kernel 3.10.17 CPU is arm-iMX6

Comment: *"I use DTS..."* -- provide it. Enable `initcall_debug` in your kernel command line and attach full dmesg to some sharing site (like pastebin.com), and share link to it.

Comment: dmesg with initcall_debug is [http://pastebin.com/nCzWLA1r]. The issue is on line 308 (driver name bt125_exp). Ther is no bt125_driver_init call.  Corect load drive is on line 766.

Comment: Link without bracket  http://pastebin.com/nCzWLA1r

Comment: Please, update you posting with new information. And like I said already, provide a DTS (overlay or full one you created).

Comment: Informations was updated in main post.

Comment: From the dmesg, it seems driver probes before the IMX I2C adapter getting registered.

    `i2c i2c-0: Failed to register i2c client bt125_exp at 0x20 (-16)
    i2c i2c-0: Failed to register i2c client ds2482 at 0x18 (-16)
    i2c i2c-0: IMX I2C adapter registered`

Comment: @SD.  How is it possible? In driver I use <pre>static struct i2c_driver</pre> so I assumed that driver will be registring after i2c. So what should I add to right dependency? Something like this: <pre>request_module("i2c")</pre>? But In others I2C device drivers there is no call this function.

Comment: Okay, I am not clear with your question and some of the comments. Which hardware is not getting probed - mcp23017 or bt125? I don't see entry for mcp23017 in dts? Can you please clarify.

Comment: @SD.  Simply both. I tryed both driver, with same issue. I think problem isn't in driver. Because program never enter to probe function (bt125_probe neither  mcp230xx_probe ).  _"From the dmesg, it seems driver probes before the IMX I2C adapter getting registered."_ I think you are right, but how to manage it? mcp23017 is gpio expander and I wrote kernel driver to manage it. So I use bt125 or mcp230(for test) driver.  Thank for help

Comment: Ignore my previous comment, in this case, the driver again try to probe and log can be seen in dmesg from line 765. In exact this situation, can you provide the contents of the i2c0 bus 'cat /sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-0/''

Also try,
1. In dts i2c@021a0000 - comment adv7180@20 and try
2. Keep  adv7180@20 commented and in encoder@20 change -reg = <0x20 0x1>; to +reg = <0x20>; and try

Answer (score 2):

I think You have multiple I2C clients with the same address (if I looked on the right DTS):

You have this client on address 0x20

```
adv7180@20 {
                compatible = "adv,adv7180";
```

And then again address 0x20:

```
encoder@20 {
                compatible = "bustec,bt125_exp";
```

Then you have client with address 0x18

```
tlv320aic3107@18 {
                compatible = "ti,tlv320aic3107";
```

and same address again:

```
            1w@18 {
                compatible = "dallas,ds2482";
```

That makes sense since you have **errno 16**

```
#define EBUSY           16      /* Device or resource busy */
```

Answer (score 1):

either the `DTS` contain the driver inclusion for the same `i2c` address twice or the second time the driver was attempted to be assigned to this `i2c` address manually without unbinding it first. in both cases the error `EBUSY` (-16) will appear in the `dmesg`. also there is a possibility the driver will be assigned to the bus but not probed in case if some internal driver kernel expecting service structures were missing or incomplete. in such case the `i2cdetect` will show the `i2c` address on already assigned driver as a numbers instead of a busy sign `UU` and there will be no `probe` messages output.